# Fact Table Design - How to capture a fact which precedes the data start date

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact-table

We have a fact table which collects information detailing when an employee selected a benefit.  The problem we are trying to solve is how to count the total benefits selected by all employee's.

We do have a BenefitSelectedOnDay flag and ordinarily, we can do a SUM on this to get a result, but this only works for benefit selections since we started loading the data.

For Example:

- Suppose Client#1 has been using our analytics tool since October 2016.  We have 4 months of data in the platform.
- When the data is loaded in October, the Benefits source data will show:

  1. Employee#1 selected a benefit on 4th April 2016.
  2. Employee#2 selected a benefit on 3rd October 2016

Setting the BenefitSelectedOnDay flag for Employee#2 is very straight forward.

The issue is what to do with Employee#1 because we can’t set a flag on a day which doesn’t exist for that client in the fact table.  Client#1's data will start on 1st October 2016.

Counting the benefit selection is problematic in some scenarios.  If we’re filtering the report by date and only looking at benefit selections in Q4 2016, we have no problem.  But, if we want a total benefit selection count, we have a problem because we haven’t set a flag for Employee#1 because the selection date precedes Client#1’s dataset range (Oct 1st 2016 - Jan 31st 2017 currently).

Comment: Could you show us what the fact looks like? It might be better to have a definite representation of a date that an employee started a benefit, rather than trying to find the date in a fact and flagging it. Perhaps there are two facts in play here

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches seem logical in your scenario:

1. Load some historical data going back as far as the first benefit selection date that is still relevant to current reporting. While it may take some work and extra space, this may be your only solution if employees qualify for different benefits based on how long the benefit has been active.
2. Add records for a single day prior to the join date (Sept 30 in this case) and flag all benefits that were selected before and are active on the Client join date (Oct 1) as being selected on that date. They will fall outside of the October reporting window but count for unbounded queries. If benefits are a binary on/off thing this should work just fine.

Personally, I would go with option 1 unless the storage requirements are ridiculous. Even then, you could load only the flagged records into the fact table. Your client might get confused if he is able to select a period prior to the joining date and get broken data, but you can explain/justify that.